# Install mysql pdo for php 7.1 for Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to install pdo mysql on ubuntu for php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

But I got E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mysql

Then I tried install from ondrej repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

Still I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mysql'
```

At the moment I haven't got any pdo modules enabled;
[image]

Can someone help please?

Comment: Try using [synaptic](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/installing-synaptic-package-manager-in-kali-linux/) to install the same

Comment: I'm running ubuntu and access it from terminal so i don't have a gui